# Do chaotic systems exist that cannot be predicted even at the limit of inifinite precision initial conditions and infinite resources?

Tags: limits, soft-question, chaos-theory

I have a layman person's understanding of the [theory of chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory), that seems to indicate that using finite-precision initial conditions and finite computing resources, chaotic systems cannot be predicted after a period of time.

My question is what happens in the limit of increasing the precision of initial conditions and resources to infinity: Does the system remain chaotic, or does the prediction window also diverge to infinity?

Specifically consider the following conditions:

1. We have a chaotic system.
2. We calculate the prediction time window  $t_\text{pred}(e,p,m,s)$ given a finite error margin $e$, for a finite precision of initial conditions $p$, and a computer with finite memory $m$ operating at a finite speed $s$.
3. We calculate the same prediction time window $t_\text{pred}(e,p,m,s)$ when precision, memory, and speed diverge to infinity together (but $e$ remains finite).

   1. If for all chaotic systems the time window diverges to infinity, then the answer to this question is *no*.
   2. If any system is found where $t_\text{pred}$ may remain finite, then the answer to this question is *yes*.

---

Since this questions seems very far from being practical I will add a motivation: I feel the answer of this question has an important impact in theology. Namely if the answer is *yes* then that would logically preclude the possibility of a non-interventionist, all-knowing god (future included) who designed the universe with a purpose, because he/she wouldn’t be able to do these calculations even if he/she was infinitely powerful.

Comment: What is the definition of prediction time window?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: The amount of time in the future for which (given the constraints), I can make a prediction with an error less than $e$. So e.g for weather it would be in the order of a few days for reasonable values of $e$.

Comment: I think I understand but you should give an example of a chaotic system to illustrate your terms.

Comment: For example, take the classic double pendulum. Moving the starting configuration just 0.001 mm in any direction has a chaotic effect on the ending position after say 10 seconds. And maybe a 0.0001 mm change is similar, and 0.00001 too, and 0.000001 etc.

Comment: @SenZen: Good idea, I will add one.

Comment: So you're question is does there exist a number $\epsilon$ small enough such that a change of $\epsilon$ in any direction does NOT result in chaotic change in the pendulum after 10 seconds, correct?

Comment: @SenZen: Not exactly. My question is more about the behaviour of $t_{pred}$. So if a accept $e = 0.0001$, with my laptop and a good measurement of initial conditions $t_{pred} = 10s$ in the above example. But what happens as I increase precision and computing power to infinity? Could $t_{pred}$ remain bound by a supremum in that scenario?

Comment: If you fix some $p$ and make stuff continuous, then the answer is no. If you want the time uniform in $p$, then the answer is yes. At least if we ignore memory and computational power (which I don't think will matter anyway).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Well that sounds like a good basis for an answer with some additional explanation. Feel free to provide one if have time :)

Comment: Could you tell me what your definition of a chaotic system is? Do you use discrete/continuous time?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: I haven't thought of that aspect to be honest, if you have a solution on either of the two scenarios it would be interesting for me

Comment: See also [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143672/the-unpredictability-of-chaos-an-intrinsic-property-or-a-matter-of-computing-p/3144787#3144787)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: I read the answer and the comments in this page, but I still don't understand this phrase of yours: "If you want the time uniform in , then the answer is yes". Could you elaborate a bit what "time uniform in $p$" means in context, and why it changes the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A crucial property of chaotic systems is that they are deterministic: There is no element of randomness in the model. The initial conditions exactly determine the future of the system.

If I simulate a chaotic model with the same initial conditions¹ on a real computer twice, I obtain exactly the same result. This only differs from the true solution for my initial conditions due to the finite precision of floating-point arithmetics (and, as the system is chaotic, this difference can be large)². And of course, in the purely hypothetical case that I want to simulate an isolated real system for which I have an exact model, I have the problem that I cannot perfectly represent my real initial conditions as floating-point numbers.

If I have arbitrary precision and infinite computing resources available as well as perfect knowledge of initial conditions, I can predict a chaotic system perfectly by simply simulating it. For a discrete-time system, the only reasons I need infinite memory and computation speed are storing and working with arbitrary precision numbers³ (and of course if I want to go infinitely into the future). For a continuous-time system, there is another reason I need infinite computing speed, namely to perform the numerical integration with arbitrarily fine time steps.

---

¹ and the same rules of floating-point arithmetics

² for a continuous-time system, the inherent imprecision of numerical integration also adds an error

³ since I end up with infinitely many digits

Comment: (+1) Very nice answer. I am only a bit confused about your last paragraph. If I fix some point $p$, then I would need a huge memory and a huge speed, but none of them need to be infinite (or if so, then I do not get why I would need it to be infinite).

Comment: This answer seems reasonable, but I will leave some time before accepting it if you don't mind, maybe someone is able to contradict this answer, or potentially provide a formal proof.

Comment: What's the difference between infinite computer memory + speed, and infinite computing power?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: *If I fix some point p, then I would need a huge memory and a huge speed, but none of them need to be infinite (or if so, then I do not get why I would need it to be infinite).* – The number of digits you need to store the state of the system grow with every time step you make. You need memory to store these. Also the more digits your numbers have, the more time you need to compute arithmetic operations with them. Depending on what your initial state is, you already need infinite memory to store it, e.g., for π (unless you are working in units of π or similar).

Comment: @SenZen: *What's the difference between infinite computer memory + speed, and infinite computing power?* – The latter is more concise.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You edited your answer! Ok so what's the difference between infinite computing speed + memory, and infinite computing resources?

Comment: @SenZen: The same.

Comment: I do not agree. If you give me some precision. Then I will only need finite memory and finite speed to get the result. In the limit I will of course need infinite ressources, but that was not my point.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft then why do you only need infinite memory and speed for discrete time but you also need infinite computing resources for continuous time? That doesn't make sense if they are the same?

Comment: @SenZen: You misunderstood the intentions of my *only* and *also.* Please see my edit.

Comment: *In the limit I will of course need infinite ressources, but that was not my point.* – I have no idea what exactly your point was, but at least that’s what I assumed to be the point of the question and what I was talking about: the limit.